# Can the list elements be generated as a PDF and be sent by mail?

Tags: apex, email, pdf

I'm pretty new to apex coding and I came across this concept of generating a PDF and mailing it. My question is can a list of elements be generated in a PDF and mailed? Say I have a list of Account names that I've generated based on some calculations. Can this list be converted to PDF and mailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to generate a PDF directly in your Apex should you wish to by generating a Blob and setting that as the attachment, along with setting the Content Type as `application/pdf`. Be wary though, because some HTML tags don't appear to work correctly, especially with Images I've found. In all honesty, I have found using an Email template more workable.

```
String pdfString = '<html><body><ol>';
for(Account account : [SELECT Name FROM Account])
{
    pdfString += '<li>' + account.Name + '</li>';
}
pdfString += '<ol></body></html>';

Blob pdfBlob = Blob.toPDF(pdfString);
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
attach.setFileName('testPdf.pdf');
attach.Body = pdfBlob;

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { email });
mail.setSubject('PDF Email Demo');
mail.setHtmlBody('Here is the email you requested! Check the attachment!');
mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 

// Send the email
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't directly generate pdf . first you need to display this in some Vf page and then render that page as pdf.
here is a code sample for your reference.

```
<apex:page controller="PdfExampleController" renderAs="pdf">
      <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="acc" border="2">
               <apex:column value="{!acc.name}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!acc.annualrevenue}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!acc.type}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!acc.accountnumber}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!acc.rating}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class PdfExampleController {
    public List accList{get;set;}
    public PdfExampleController (){
        accList = [select id,name,type,accountnumber,annualrevenue,Rating from account limit 10];
    }
}
```

Here is code sample to send this pdf in email

```
public PageReference sendPdf() {

    PageReference pdf = Page.PdfGeneratorTemplate;
    // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',accountId);

    // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
    Blob body;

    try {

      // returns the output of the page as a PDF
      body = pdf.getContent();

    // need to pass unit test -- current bug  
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
      body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
    }

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
    attach.setFileName('testPdf.pdf');
    attach.setInline(false);
    attach.Body = body;

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { email });
    mail.setSubject('PDF Email Demo');
    mail.setHtmlBody('Here is the email you requested! Check the attachment!');
    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 

    // Send the email
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Email with PDF sent to '+email));

    return null;

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there no way I can directly generate it from my apex class?

Comment: I don't think. you can give it a try but i am no sure but in this way you can generate. pass your list to this controller and then get this page body as pdf. It will work for you.

Comment: +1, but you should be able to create the PDF in the Apex, i've added an answer.